# How to split all or part of a directory listing into two separate strings

Tags: c#, split, directory

I found an instance where I need to be able to split a portion of a given directory listing/path. In this case I have path `"C:\Program Files(x86)\MyApp\Data"` or "`C:\Program Files\MyApp\Data\myfile.txt"` and I'd like to remove everything before `\MyApp\Data\` so I can use it for future processing.

I know that I can do something similar to following to split up each directory and I could just rebuild it from there but I'd like to be able to split the unwanted path information - keeping only the relevant string.

```
string mypath = @"C:\Program Files(x86)\MyApp\Data";
string[] directories = mypath.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
```

Comment: Before you start using regexes on hard-coded strings, tell us what you are going to be using this for. Are you trying to get the path to the data directory of an application installed by the user? That's stored in the AppDomain DataDirectory property. Or maybe you want the running app path? That's `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`. Are either of those the "given directory" you are looking for?

Comment: The path is to the data directory of an installed application. I've queried the registry for the given path and am trying to get the application specific path (ex. \MyApp\Data\)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extract a substring from the position where the desired part begins:

```
string s1 = @"C:\Program Files(x86)\MyApp\Data";
string s2 = @"\MyApp\Data\";

int index = s1.IndexOf(s2);
if ( index >= 0 )
{
    string end = s1.Substring(index);
    string beg = s1.Substring(0, index);
}
```

but consider, if you may have a `\` symbol at the end of both strings or not:

```
int index = s1.IndexOf(s2.TrimEnd('\\'));
```

Comment: If s1 does not contain `\MyApp\Data` then `IndexOf(s2);` returns -1 resulting in an exception from `s1.Substring`.

Comment: @Trisped obviously it does. I guess the OP just needs to get the right direction, while all the corner cases he'll be able to workaround on his own.

Answer (score 1):

Just split on MyApp\Data and remove the first entry:

```
     string mypath = @"C:\Program Files(x86)\MyApp\Data";
     string[] directories = mypath.Split(new string[] {@"\MyApp\Data"},  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

     string mySavePath = mypath.Remove(0, directories[0].Length); 
     Console.WriteLine(mySavePath);
```